# How to print individual row from foreach?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a foreach array in php in which i am displaying records that has many rows and my view file is as follows,

```
         <?php
          $count = 1;
          foreach ($resultlist as $student) {
            ?>
            <div class="slide-row" id="printableArea" style="padding:30px;border:2px solid #999;">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <label> Name: </label>
                      <?php echo $student['firstname']; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                      <label> Standard: </label>
                      <?php echo $student['class']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                      <label> Section: </label>
                      <?php echo $student['section']; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                      <label> Admission No: </label>
                      <?php echo $student['admission_no']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                      <label> House: </label>
                      <!-- <?php echo $student['section']; ?> -->
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                      <label> Religion: </label>
                      <?php echo $student['religion']; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                      <label> Caste: </label>
                      <?php echo $student['cast']; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail width150" alt="Cinque Terre" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>backend/dist/img/jeevaschool.png" alt="Image">
                </div>
              </div>
              <br>
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Community</th>
                    <th>DOB</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Blood Group</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $student['community']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $student['dob']; ?></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><?php echo $student['blood_group']; ?></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label> Name of the Father: </label>
                  <?php echo $student['father_name']; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label> Occupation: </label>
                  <?php echo $student['father_occupation']; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label> Name of the Mother: </label>
                  <?php echo $student['mother_name']; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label> Occupation: </label>
                  <?php echo $student['mother_occupation']; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label> Mobile Number: </label>
                  <?php echo $student['mobileno']; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label> Email ID: </label>
                  <?php echo $student['email']; ?>
                </div>
              </div><br><br>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="printDiv('printableArea');">Print</button>
            <br><br><br>
              <?php
            }
            $count++;
          }
          ?>
      </div>
```

The records were displaying one by one and i need to print each row individually by clicking print button on respective row.

I have the html with id

```
<div class="slide-row" id="printableArea" style="padding:30px;border:2px solid #999;">
```

And print button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="printDiv('printableArea');">Print</button>
```

JS

```
  function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

I tried with the above one and it will print only first row of record, but i am in the need to get the respective print result for each individual rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Id` should be unique in a page. As per your code there will be many elements with id `printableArea` in your page. Instead, you can add dynamic Ids.

For example, add your count variable to Ids

```
<div class="slide-row" id="printableArea_<?php echo $count; ?>" style="padding:30px;border:2px solid #999;">
```

In your button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="printDiv('printableArea_<?php echo $count; ?>');">Print</button>
```